# Why is u-equivalence useful?

Tags: nonstandard-analysis

If $X$ is a standard set, we define, for $\alpha\in\ ^*X$,

$U_{\alpha}=\{A\subset X\mid\alpha\in\ ^*A\}$. We can see that $U_\alpha$ is an ultrafilter on $X$.

We thus define an equivalence relation on $^*X$ which is $\alpha\sim\beta$ iff $U_{\alpha}=U_{\beta}$.

Is it possible, using big enough saturation, that there are distinct $\alpha,\beta\in\ ^*X$ such that $\alpha\sim\beta$ (for example, using [this](http://people.dm.unipi.it/dinasso/papers/05.pdf)) ?

Answer (score 1):

The paper by Di Nasso you cite was published in 2002.  In a latter paper by Benci, Forti and Di Nasso:

> Benci, Vieri; Forti, Marco; Di Nasso, Mauro.
>   The eightfold path to nonstandard analysis. Nonstandard methods and applications in mathematics,  3–44, 
>   Lect. Notes Log., 25, Assoc. Symbol. Logic, La Jolla, CA, 2006

in section 9 seeks to present models of hyperintegers as *subsets* of the Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb Z$.  This suggests that for those models distinct integers necessarily correspond to distinct ultrafilters.

Meanwhile Di Nasso in chapter 11 of *Nonstandard analysis for the working mathematician*, page 445, points out that $c^+$ saturation implies that the map from hypernaturals to $\beta \mathbb N$ (the Stone-Cech compactification) is onto. It suffices to choose a model of the hypernaturals of high enough cardinality (namely, higher than that of $\beta\Bbb N$) to ensure that there are distinct hypernaturals that define identical ultrafilters on $\Bbb N$.